# Downloading an .XLSX-file from the public folder in React fails in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, file, xlsx

The following code works just fine locally, with my .xlsx located in the public folder:

```
          <Button
            variant="text"
            as="a"
            download
            href={url}
            target="_blank"
          >
            Download
          </Button>
```

However, when I deploy the code to production (and test also), downloading the.xlsx-file says that the file is corrupted with the following message, with 30% the size of the original file. Anyone have any idea what's going on here?: [image]